# Crystal Reports 9 and Sql Server Synonyms?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

We use a variety of Schemas in our SQL Server 2005 installations. Crystal Reports works with those properly but I have a third party app that won't render the Crystal Reports that use different Schemas (no clue why). Is it possible to get Crystal to recognize a table that is addressed by a Synonym?  If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Crystal Reports shows only tables, views and stored procedures in the Database Expert. One way to access a synonym is by creating a **command**. Double-click on "**Add Command**" in the Database Expert and enter a SELECT query to load data from the synonym.